# Need to get dynamic date range base on max post payload size in DataWeave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have to send some data to a third-party system. I have a limitation that I can only send an average of 5 records. (Actual number is many hundreds of millions). I am getting these records from Salesforce. I am writing a SOQL query to get the data using the created_date time stamp between two date ranges. As I can only send an average of 5 records per request, I have to limit the data returned by SOQL query by adjusting the created_date date range.

So I have to dynamically figure out the created_date range to be used in my queries.For doing this, I am first firing a SOQL query to get the number of records per day as shown below

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) total, DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) date
        FROM Account
        WHERE CreatedDate >= 2019-10-11T00:00:00Z AND   CreatedDate <= 2019-12-03T23:59:59Z
        GROUP BY DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) order by DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate)
```

Suppose this gives me below result.

```
[
  {
    "total": "1",
    "date": "2019-10-11"
  },
  {
    "total": "2",
    "date": "2019-10-17"
  },
  {
    "total": "2",
    "date": "2019-10-24"
  },
  {
    "total": "4",
    "date": "2019-10-30"
  },
  {
    "total": "5",
    "date": "2019-10-31"
  },
  {
    "total": "6",
    "date": "2019-11-01"
  },
  {
    "total": "1",
    "date": "2019-11-04"
  },
  {
    "total": "1",
    "date": "2019-11-06"
  },
  {
    "total": "1",
    "date": "2019-11-07"
  },
  {
    "total": "2",
    "date": "2019-11-08"
  },
  {
    "total": "6",
    "date": "2019-11-19"
  },
  {
    "total": "2",
    "date": "2019-11-20"
  },
  {
    "total": "2",
    "date": "2019-11-21"
  },
  {
    "total": "4",
    "date": "2019-11-22"
  },
  {
    "total": "1",
    "date": "2019-11-26"
  },
  {
    "total": "2",
    "date": "2019-11-27"
  },
  {
    "total": "4",
    "date": "2019-12-02"
  },
  {
    "total": "1",
    "date": "2019-12-03"
  }
]
```

I want to go through each date and the total number of Salesforce records on these dates. For the first query fromCreateDate is going to fix "2019-10-11". Now I have to find the toCreateDate by summing the total number of records for the next days in the list until their sum becomes less than or equal to 5.

So, after the first iteration, I got fromCreatDate and toCreatDate, as shown below from the first date eg. 2019-10-11 to 2019-10-24 as the sum of the total, equals 5.

```
[{
"fromCreatDate" : "2019-10-11"
"toCreatDate" : "2019-10-24"
}]
```

Now for the next date ranges, my fromCreatDate will be the next date from last toCreatDate e.g 2019-10-30 which has a total of 4. But if add 4 to the next date total, the sum will become greater than 5. So It would just take some date a toCreateDate. The next date is having a total of 5, so it would have the same date as the to and from created date. The next date is having a total of 6, so it would have the same date as the to and from created date. The next 4 days total is a sum of 5 days. So their dates will become to and from the created date and this logic will go on.

**Expected output**

```
 [{
    "fromCreatDate" : "2019-10-11"
    "toCreatDate" : "2019-10-24"
    },
    {
    "fromCreatDate" : "2019-10-30"
    "toCreatDate" : "2019-10-30"
    },
    {
    "fromCreatDate" : "2019-10-31"
    "toCreatDate" : "2019-10-31"
    },
    {
    "fromCreatDate" : "2019-11-01"
    "toCreatDate" : "2019-11-01"
    },
    {
    "fromCreatDate" : "2019-11-04"
    "toCreatDate" : "2019-11-08"
    },
    {
    "fromCreatDate" : "2019-11-19"
    "toCreatDate" : "2019-11-19"
    },
    {
    "fromCreatDate" : "2019-11-20"
    "toCreatDate" : "2019-11-21"
    },
    {
    "fromCreatDate" : "2019-11-22"
    "toCreatDate" : "2019-11-26"
    },
    {
    "fromCreatDate" : "2019-11-27"
    "toCreatDate" : "2019-11-27"
    }

]
```

I would than do forEach on above array and create dynamic SOQL queries.

This function should also give date range when sum of total is less than 5.
For example, if I just pass below payload.

```
[
  {
    "total": "1",
    "date": "2019-10-11"
  },
  {
    "total": "2",
    "date": "2019-10-17"
  }
]
```

I should get output as

```
[{
"fromCreatDate" : "2019-10-11"
"toCreatDate" : "2019-10-17"
}]
```

as the total of 1 and 2 is less than 5.

Comment: What happens when the sum of previous plus current item is greater than 5 (example: 4 + 2)? What happens when the current item exceeds 5 (example: 2 + 6)?

Comment: Sorry for late response. 1) If sum of previous and current exceeds 5, take date range from previous and then again check, if current and next are equal to or greater than 5. If current item exceeds five like 2+6. There should be date range for 2 and 6 separately.

Answer (score 1):

I created this recursive function to calculate the ranges for any total number. The logic to group elements was not fully consistent in my understanding so there is a difference in the expected output at day 19. If you clarify the logic more it should not be difficult to adapt it.

I added a wrapper function so the initial call doesn't need extra arguments.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun getRangeofMaxTotal(list, maxTotal)=
    do {
        fun getRangeInternal(list, maxTotal, previousDate, previousTotal)=
            do {
                var thisTotal=(list[0].total default 0) as Number
                var thisDate=list[0].date
                var fromDate=previousDate default thisDate
                var lastTotal=previousTotal default 0
                ---
                if (isEmpty(list)) []
                else if ((thisTotal + lastTotal) == maxTotal) 
                        {fromCreatDate: fromDate, toCreatDate: thisDate} >> getRangeInternal( list[1 to -1], maxTotal, null, 0)
                    else if ((thisTotal + lastTotal) > maxTotal) 
                        {fromCreatDate: fromDate, toCreatDate: fromDate} >> getRangeInternal( list[1 to -1], maxTotal, thisDate, thisTotal)
                    else
                        getRangeInternal( list[1 to -1], maxTotal, fromDate, thisTotal + lastTotal) 
                        
            }
        ---
        getRangeInternal(payload, maxTotal, null, 0)
    }
---
getRangeofMaxTotal(payload, 5)
```

Output

```json
[
  {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-10-11",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-10-24"
  },
  {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-10-30",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-10-30"
  },
  {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-10-31",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-10-31"
  },
  {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-11-01",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-11-01"
  },
  {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-11-04",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-11-08"
  },
  {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-11-19",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-11-19"
  },
  {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-11-19",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-11-19"
  },
  {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-11-20",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-11-20"
  },
  {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-11-22",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-11-26"
  },
  {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-11-27",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-11-27"
  },
  {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-12-02",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-12-03"
  }
]
```

Comment: I started to learn recursive funtion from your one of the solution on other post 2 years bak, did not know I will be having a direct encouter. Thanks aled for your time first of all. As you have already pointed out, everything is coming as expected in the output except ` {
    "total": "2",
    "date": "2019-11-20"
  },
  {
    "total": "2",
    "date": "2019-11-21"
  }`
The logic to group the total is, if sum of total is equal to 5 , group it. I sum is just exceding 5 , dont group it, use it as it is like 6. If after grouping sum is coming closer to 5 like adding 2 and 2 which is 4

Comment: {
    "total": "2",
    "date": "2019-11-20"
  },
  {
    "total": "2",
    "date": "2019-11-21"
  },
  {
    "total": "4",
    "date": "2019-11-22"
  },
  {
    "total": "1",
    "date": "2019-11-26"
  } like. here, Your function is giving everything correct is just missing this data  {
    "total": "2",
    "date": "2019-11-20"
  },
  {
    "total": "2",
    "date": "2019-11-21"
  } and giving  {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-11-19",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-11-19"
  } twice

Comment: {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-11-19",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-11-19"
  } instead of this it should be  {
    "fromCreatDate": "2019-11-20",
    "toCreatDate": "2019-11-21"
  } as 2 + 2 is 4 which is less than 5, but adding next date total whould make totoal 8 , so we have to stuck with last 2 days to keep total less than 5

Comment: I am going through this code and see if I can get the logic. But thank a log aled, this is 95% what I was looking for.

Comment: You need to clarify the criteria to group records. Please don't use comments for that because it gets too confusing. Edit the question and clarify what happens if the total is less than 5, equal to 5 and greater to 5, with examples. I'm not fully sure the expected output actually complies with the criteria. I recommend to add for each item what is the carry from the previous item and the new total. Otherwise it is too easy to get lost in the middle

Comment: I understand @aled. Just added a scenario in the description which is still missing. Other scenarios are working as expected. When the sum is less than 5 , it should also provide it in the output.